# Add new input box

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this code and just wondering how to insert new input box with different name and value.

**This is the current code I have: [Edited]**

```
public function form( $instance )
{
    $user_id = isset ( $instance['user_id'] ) ? $instance['user_id'] : array();
    $user_id_num = count( $user_id );
    $user_id[ $user_id_num + 1 ] = '';
    $user_loc = isset ( $instance['user_loc'] ) ? $instance['user_loc'] : array();
    $user_loc_num = count( $user_loc );
    $user_loc[ $user_loc_num + 1 ] = '';
    $user_html = array();
    $user_id_counter = 0;
    $user_loc_counter = 0;

    foreach ( $user_id as $name => $value )
    {
        $user_html[] = sprintf(
            'User ID<br/><input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat">Location<br/><input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat">',
            $this->get_field_name( 'user_id' ),
            $user_id_counter,
            esc_attr( $value ),
            $this->get_field_name( 'user_loc' ),
            $user_loc_counter,
            esc_attr( $value )
        );
        $user_id_counter += 1;
        $user_loc_counter += 1;
    }

    print 'New User' . join( '<br />', $user_id_html );
}
```

What this code does is it will auto generate new input field for **User ID** once the setting is saved.

My problem is how will I be able to insert new input field for **Location** `user_loc` next to the **User ID** field so that when I enter new **User ID** and **Location** it will generate 2 new input field for **User ID** and **Location**.

**The code I wanted to add shows something like this:**

```
Location<br/> <input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat">
```

Next to

```
User ID<br/><input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them side-by-side then you are going to have to wrap each on in a div (to keep the prompts aligned with each input ad adjusted using CSS (otherwise use a table). Then you need to adjust your php code:

```
$user_id_html[] = sprintf(
   '<div>User ID<br/><input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat"></div><div>Location<br/> <input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat">',
   $this->get_field_name( 'user_id' ),
   $user_id_counter,
   esc_attr( $value ),
   //--- add the extra parameters for the location
);
```

Comment: Ok I think that I getting the idea now.. I edited the code above and the new input field for Location is now displaying but the value on the User ID displays the value of the Location. :(

Comment: View the source code of the page and post the relevant code back here.

Comment: I'm on the widget admin and this is what shows on source code `<form action="" method="post">
 <div class="widget-content">
New UserUser ID<br/><input type="text" name="widget-t5_array_options_widget[__i__][user_id][0]" value="" class="widefat">Location<br/><input type="text" name="widget-t5_array_options_widget[__i__][user_id][0]" value="" class="widefat"> </div>
 </form>`

Comment: OK, the html is correct and it is clear to see that both values are the same. Why this is happening I am not sure. You will need to debug your code. Put var_dump($this->get_field_name( 'user_id' ),$this->get_field_name( 'user_loc' )); just before the $user_html[] statement. Maybe this will help find the problem.

Comment: Isn't the `name="[user_id][0]` for the Location supposed to display `name="[user_loc][0]` I think the problem is with the `foreach ( $user_id as $name => $value )
  {` don't you think?

Comment: Yep, you need to get the value from the user_loc field.

Comment: Would you mind helping me with that one? I tried `foreach ( $user_id as $name => $value ) && ( $user_id as $name => $value )` but did not work :(